# Rails Internationalization with Rails data from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, internationalization

I would like to use rails I18n. I am using the Bootstrap popButton with this code:

```
<button class="btn btn-disabled pull-right", id ="popButton", data-content= "<%= t('cars.partials.received.yesOrNo', time: "<%= Car.last.model %>") %>" >
```

But the problem is,

I can not call `<%= %>` inside another `<%= %>`. If I type something to `time:`
like;

```
<button class="btn btn-disabled pull-right", id ="popButton", data-content= "<%= t('cars.partials.received.yesOrNo', time: "etc etc") %>" >
```

that works. But I would like to call from database. How should I call it?

Thank you

Comment: you cannot neste rails tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside `<%= %>` is actual ruby code, so `<%= t('cars.partials.received.yesOrNo', time: Car.last.model) %>` should work. I would avoid calling your model directly in the template and would rather pass it in as a variable from the controller.

E.g.

Controller action:

`@last_car = Car.last`

Template:

`<%= t('cars.partials.received.yesOrNo', time: @last_car.model) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Link: [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations)

## app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<%=t 'greet_username', user: "Bill", message: "Goodbye" %>
```

## config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```